# Where are the possible ways to set system properties

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a NetBeans web application project. I recently moved the project to a different directory. Now, the code (java) no longer finds the props directory. I thought I was setting it in Project Properties|Run|VM Options like this:

-DPropsDir=c:\development\projects\[old dir]\config

So, I changed it to new dir. However, when the code tries to read the PropsDir system property with

```
System.getProperty("PropsDir");
```

It returns the old dir. I cleared the NetBeans cache. I searched the entire HDD for any reference to the old dir or any kind of windows system variable without any luck. So, I have no idea on where it is still being set to the old dir.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project you want to move in the "projects" tab, and then click "move". This will allow you to move the project to a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I figured out where it is set. For a web application, you need to set the VM options under the Services tab on the Netbeans IDE, then Servers|Apache Tomcat| Platform tab|VM Options. Apparently, the Project Properties|Run|VM Options is of no significance in this case, since it's really using the tomcat VM.